# Cloudfront restricting to IPs in bucket policy

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am working on a demo website using AWS S3 and have restricted to certain number of IPs using a bucket policy (e.g).

```
{
"Id": "S3PolicyId1",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "IPDeny",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "*"
        },
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-wicked-awesome-bucket/*",
        "Condition": {
            "NotIpAddress": {
                "aws:SourceIp": "XX.XX.XX.XX/XX"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

}

This works nicely. Now I want to use CloudFront to serve the website over HTTPS on a custom domain. I have created the distribution and the bucket policy has been modified (to allow CloudFront access) but I keep getting an access denied error when I try to access the CloudFront URL.

Is it possible to still use the bucket policy IP access list using CloudFront? If so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 3):

You can remove the IP blacklisting/ whitelisting from S3 bucket policy and attach AWS WAF with the required access rules to the CloudFront distribution.

Note: Make sure when you make the S3 bucket private, to setup the Origin Access Identity User properly both in CloudFront and S3. Also if the bucket is in a different region than North Virginia, it can take some time for the DNS propagation.

Comment: Thanks Ashan. I am trying to utilise the AWS free tier for the moment which I don't think includes the WAF. Any alternatives?

Comment: With CloudFront, only option is WAF for whitelisting.

Comment: OK, I may have to fall back to this. Basic auth may be an option as opposed to IP but I'm not sure that makes it any easier.

Answer (score 3):

A lambda function that changes the Bucket policy based on changes in the published list of IPs [Here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html)

The function can be invoked by SNS topic monitoring the list of IP's. [Here is the documentation on that.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-lambda.html)

Here is the SNS topic for it.

`arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:806199016981:AmazonIpSpaceChanged`